# Will the Veda competence be lost without any Hindu country? As per purana, did Veda prosper outside a Hindu rajya?

Tags: kali-yuga, brahmins, adharma

All know the scripture was entrusted to people with the onerous task of holding, passing, and ensuring accuracy of body and meaning of scripture. It is a very difficult life to be a vidwan Brahman, often resulting in starvation, poverty, extreme control on diet and discipline, and often early death. Death and banishment for losing debates. What does scripture say about loss of dharma in Kaliyug? Does it mean loss of the religion?